# Google app maker Side bar or menu bar

Tags: google-app-maker

In sample projects left navigation or menu bar is shown and hide based on the button click on the header.

Left navigation links is created as fragment, but it is not called is any of the pages, but hide and show is working. Can any one show how it works.

We tried similar thing in our project but it is not working can anyone explain how it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Starter App template](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/starter-app/) side-menu link's clicks are propagated to its parent panel and handled by it. Here is MenuItemPanel click handler for reference:

```js
app.pageFragments.Menu.properties.IsVisible = false;
app.showPage(app.pages.SomePage);
```

Every page in the app has menu page fragment and its `visible` property is bound to Menu page fragment's `IsVisible` [custom property](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties)(it is kind of bindable global variable).

Comment: Thanks pavel, we got it